# Determining the equation of a line parallel to two planes.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

**The task is to find the equation of a line that intersects lines $\textbf{p1}$ and $\textbf{p2}$, and is parallel to the planes $\textbf{T1}$ and $\textbf{T2}$ the equations are:

$$\textbf{p1:} \quad \frac{x+5}{2} = \frac{y-3}{-4} = \frac{z+1}{3} $$

$$\textbf{p2:} \quad \frac{x-3}{-2} = \frac{y+1}{3} = \frac{z+2}{4}$$

$$\textbf{T1:}\quad  3x+12y-3z-5=0$$

$$\textbf{T2:} \quad 3x-4y+9z+7=0$$

If anyone has an idea for this task and similar tasks please share!

**

Comment: This portion of my Real Analysis comprehension has cobwebs.  My **guess** is that the equation of a plane parallel to $T_1$ must have form: $3x + 12y - 3z = k$.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so we know this line is parallel to both T1 and T2. which means it must be perpendicular to both of their normal vectors, given by

$\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 12 & -3
\end{bmatrix}$
and
$\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -4 & 9
\end{bmatrix}$

if you find the cross product of these two vectors you will get the directional vector of the line and then by using P1 or P2 we can find an initial point.

Comment: How do you find the initial point ?

Comment: Use the equations of $P_1$ and $P_2$ to find their point of intersection, let's call it $p_3$. 
The cross product that Deepak has spoken about (the cross product of the two normal vectors) will be the direction vector ($d$). Once you find that, the equation of the line you need is $p_3 + \lambda d$.

Comment: Could I find the equation's by doing this: write parametric equations for the intersection point of the searched line and p1, by this i will get 3 equations with 5 unknown variables, and do the same thing for the searched line and p2 and now I will get additional one unknown parametar of line p2, and also I can write down 2 more equations from the fact that they intersection at some point and I would get a system that could be solve. So is this a valid solution,because this is the first thing that comes to mi mind?

Comment: @TemzaVelickov Try both methods, see what you get :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The direction of the line is given by the cross-product of the normals to the planes. If you project the two lines parallelly to this direction to some plane, their 2D intersection is the projection of the searched line.